# .htaccess RewriteEngine not working for secondary GET

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm creating friendly links in my site, but I have a problem. I wrote this, but only the first line of code is working, and I'n not sure why:

```
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) user.php?user=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/options user.php?user=$1&options [NC,L]
```

When I go to `test.com/user/tom` everything is fine, but when I try `test.com/user/tom/options` it just loda the same page.

I have php script that should load different pages, for different `$_GET`, and its working if used with normal links.

Comment: because catch first row... 
if you can change second line ^user to another name ...

Comment: I didn't know it's working this way! thanks, just swapped the lines :)

Comment: Did switching the line really worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

The correct thing to do here is *not* to swap the lines around. Whilst that may fix your problem, it will also send `user/tom/foo/bar` to the first rule. The reason it does this is because the pattern is not closed with `$`. As such, your rules should read as follows:

```bash
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ user.php?user=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/options$ user.php?user=$1&options [NC,L]
```

> **Tip:** If you also have other pages for the user, you can simplify the second rule to include different segments by means of a capture:
>
> ```bash
> RewriteRule ^user/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/(options|other-page)$ user.php?user=$1&$2 [NC,L]
> ```
>
> Also giving consideration to the fact that you are using the `NC` (no case) flag, you can drop the `A-Z` in your capture groups. You can also use `\d` for digits. Example `[a-z\d]+`